# Añadir una nueva ENI (Interfaz de Red) en instancia Centos7 EC2 AWS Amazon

Tags: linux, aws, centos, redes, ec2

Tengo una instancia EC2 con Linux Centos7 al agregar la nueva interfaz y luego de ejecutar el comando `ifconfig` no aparece la nueva interfaz, pero si ejecuto `ifconfig -a` si me muestra la interfaz de esta manera
[ifconfig -a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7dSX.png) y si reinicio la instancia no produce ningún efecto, ademas no se crea el archivo ifcfg correspondiente y al momento de crearlo y luego de reiniciar el servicio de red pierdo conexión via SSH y debo quitar la nueva interfaz de red, reiniciar para poder conectarme sin problema.
Todas las soluciones que existen en los foros de AWS se refieren a las instancia Amazon Linux y que tengo no lo es, es una AMI proporcionada por Centos.org.
Agradeceria de sobremanera si alguien tuviese algún tutorial que pueda seguir para solucionar mi problema

Muchas Gracias de Antemano!